# Warning Project references Implentations.csproj could not be resolved

Tags: asp.net, .net, monodevelop

I have a project on monodevelop set up like such:

- Interfaces

  - No References
- Implementations

  - References:

    - Interfaces
- Object Mapper

  - References:

    - Interfaces
    - Implementations
- Consumer

  - References:

    - Interfaces
    - Object Mapper

When I compile my project, no errors appear, but I do get a warning:

```
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: Warning: Project reference '../Implementations/Implementations.csproj' could not be resolved. (Consumer)
```

Why am I getting this warning, and should I resolve it?

EDIT: So when I give Consumer a reference to Implementations, this warning disappears. However, I don't want my consumer project to know anything about the implementation. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I am also having this problem, tad bit more severe. guessing this is because they may have changed the compiler behavior regarding cd-ing into project directories.
Build: 0 errors, 6337 warnings

Comment: @Behrooz do the errors affect the behavior of your app?

Comment: nah, As far as i can tell everything works. and the compiler is 6x-8x faster than before.